# Upgrade to EF 6.1.1 makes effect of [NotMapped] disappear

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-6

I have upgraded from EF 4.3.1 to 6.1.1 and now it seems like the annotation [NotMapped] is useless. Yes, i have change to correct assembly and everything looks fine on compilation.

Everywhere where [NotMapped] is present the property is handled as a domain property and i get an error that EF can't find the matching column in database.

Example:

```
private bool _authenticated = true;

        [NotMapped]
        public bool Authenticated
        {
            get { return _authenticated; }
            set { _authenticated = value; }
        }
```

Yes, it seems like i can work around this by adding...

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Ignore(x => x.Authenticated);
```

...but then, whats the use of [NotMapped] in EF6?

(Worked perfect before upgrade)

Comment: Is there some code around where you're encountering the exception?

Comment: Everywhere i do a get, update or put to database and the [NotMapped] property i included i get the error: Invalid column name 'Authenticated'. (or whatever the column/property is called). In this case with User object the code is a simple repository call:         public virtual T FirstOrDefault(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
        {
            return _objectSet.FirstOrDefault(where);
        }

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved by first uninstall and then reinstalling EF on all projects in the solution.

I think it was some mismatch in .NET versions for some projects when i upgraded to EF6 the first time which made the system take the [NotMapped] annotaition from the wrong assembly (.NET instead of EF).

This led me to it: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2d682be0-daca-45c4-ad76-5885acc6004f/possible-bug-with-inheritance-and-notmapped?forum=adodotnetentityframework

...and most the line: "If you use the new
 annotations from the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll assembly in .NET 4.5
 they will not be processed by Code First."

Comment: I'm seeing this issue on my EF 6.1.3 project. My WebAPI's "Put" method gives me a ModelState error on a property I marked NotMapped. Funny, it's only for _one_ of the 3 *NotMap* properties that I'm seeing the error, however.

Comment: In my case, the prop is of type `NameValueCollection`, and I cannot even use the `OnModelCreating` fluent api to declare it not mapped - the intellisense is telling me it must be a non-nullable type.

Answer (score 3):

I also think that there is some mismatch with the .NET version and EF6, which made the program take the [NotMapped] annotation from a wrong assembly.

In particular, the problem is on the use of these two references:  System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations; 
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.

I noted that, in this situation, we can not use both reference on same class file, because the NotMapped attribute will be assigned to a different dll of the expected. Even if you assign one of this reference in the code without putting the directive **using** (putting the complete reference on the attribute declaration, for instance), the program will still have this bug.

To solve this problem, I removed the reference System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations from the class, leaving only the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema reference to use the NotMapped attribute. And to supply the miss of the first reference (form validation actions), I implemented the validation on the client-side (using jquery + javascript).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
//using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

public partial class Account
{       

    //[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo nome é obrigatório!")]
    //[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "O campo nome deve possuir no máximo 50 caracteres!")]
    //[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Display(Name = "Nome")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo nome é obrigatório!")]
    //[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "O campo email deve possuir no máximo 100 caracteres!")]
    //[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    //[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo senha é obrigatório!")]
    //[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Display(Name = "Senha")]
    //[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.Password)]
    [NotMapped]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    //[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo confirmação de senha é obrigatório!")]
    //[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Display(Name = "Confirmação da senha")]
    //[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.Password)]
    //[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "A confirmação da senha está diferente da senha informada.")]
    [NotMapped]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party, but I had this case:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;//I needed this for [Key] attribute on another property
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;//this one is for [NotMapped]
...
[ScriptIgnore]
[NotMapped]
public System.Timers.Timer Timer { get; set; }
```

This would generate outrageous stuff like:

```
AddColumn("dbo.mytable", "Timer_AutoReset", c => c.Boolean(nullable: false));
AddColumn("dbo.mytable", "Timer_Enabled", c => c.Boolean(nullable: false));
AddColumn("dbo.mytable", "Timer_Interval", c => c.Double(nullable: false));
```

Experimenting with this I came to the conclusion that `[NotMapped]` is ignored if there is another attribute on the column. If it is possible - in my case it was - remove it and `[NotMapped]` won't be ignored.

Comment: Just encountered the same issue. Looks like this is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I had was with an out-dated .EDMX file (created to speed up the application startup time). It was generated prior to the [NotMapped] property being added so the property so the "NotMapped" property was included.

Regenerating the .EDMX file after adding the NotMapped attribute fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I think the NotMapped has to be the first attribute above the element. This works if not then it doesn't work.

Comment: This is simply not true. Please only post answers of which you're convinced they're correct. Not "I think".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34992023)