# NotMapped attribute not working on a specific property in a model

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a model that contains some calculated properties. To prevent these properties from being detected by the EF model (as they should not be included in the database model), I use the NotMapped property. This usually works as expected, and that is also the case for this model, except for one single property.

```
[NotMapped]
public PaymentStatus PaymentStatus => IsPaid
   ? PaymentStatus.Paid
   : Payments.Any()
       ? Payments.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedAt).First().Status
       : PaymentStatus.Null;
```

When I run the project I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: No backing field could be found for property 'Order.PaymentStatus' and the property does not have a setter.

When I explicitly Ignore the property in my DbContext using the Fluent API, the application does run.

Other than this property, the model contains several other NotMapped properties, which are ignored as they should..

What could be the issue that NotMapped does not seem to work for this property, but does for others?

Comment: Check that no Linq2EF query is referencing the PaymentStatus property such as in a `Where` or `Select` expression etc. Use a Find Usages on the property and review each instance to make sure it isn't appearing in a query.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was the issue. I have a self-made package, which goes through all registered models in the assembly and sets the Enum to string conversion for each Enum property. This did not take into account if the property was decorated with [NotMapped] attribute. After solving this, it works as expected!

Answer (score 0):

I found out (thanks to Steve Py) that a process in the OnModelCreating of my DbContext was referencing the property without taking the [NotMapped] attribute into account. This process sets Enum to String conversion in the database for all Enum properties in the assembly, so it happens using reflection, which made it hard to debug this particular issue. After making sure this flow ignores properties with the [NotMapped] attribute, it works as expected!

Answer (score -1):

I think is a mismatch between the .NET version and EF6 and the program it's not calling [NotMapped] from the correct assembly. Try to read this other [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25646756/upgrade-to-ef-6-1-1-makes-effect-of-notmapped-disappear).